# Re-assigning an std::function object while inside its execution

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, std-function

I have an std::function object I'm using as a callback to some event. I'm assigning a lambda to this object, within which, I assign the object to a different lambda mid execution. I get a segfault when I do this. Is this not something I'm allowed to do? If so, why? And how would I go about achieving this?

declaration:

```
std::function<void(Data *)> doCallback;
```

calling:

```
//
// This gets called after a sendDataRequest call returns with data
//
void onIncomingData(Data *data)
{
    if ( doCallback )
    {
        doCallback(data);
    }
}
```

assignment:

```
doCallback =
    [=](Data *data)
    {
        //
        // Change the callback within itself because we want to do 
        // something else after getting one request  
        //
        doCallback =
            [=](Data *data2)
            {
                ... do some work ...
            };
        sendDataRequest();
    };
sendDataRequest();
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with a small, compilable testcase (e.g. without the data communication)? This would go a long way towards helping you (by giving everyone a chance to debug through the program etc.).

Comment: What LucDanton says. Can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: I assume `sendDataRequest();` introduces an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 2):

The standard does not specify when in the operation of `std::function::operator()` that the function uses its internal state object.  In practice, some implementations use it after the call.

So what you did was undefined behaviour, and in particular it crashes.

```
struct bob {
  std::function<void()> task;
  std::function<void()> next_task;
  void operator()(){
    next_task=task;
    task();
    task=std::move(next_task);
  }
}
```

now if you want to change what happens when you next invoke `bob` within `bob()`, simply set `next_task`.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**

It depends on whether, after the (re)assignment, the lambda being called accesses any of its non static data members or not. If it does then you get undefined behavior. Otherwise, I believe nothing bad should happen.

**Long answer**

In the OP's example, a lambda object -- denoted here by `l_1` -- held by a `std::function` object is invoked and, during its execution, the `std::function` object is assigned to another lambda -- denoted here by `l_2`.

The assignment calls `template<class F> function& operator=(F&& f);` which, by 20.8.11.2.1/18, has the effects of

```
function(std::forward<F>(f)).swap(*this);
```

where `f` binds to `l_2` and `*this` is the `std::function` object being assigned to. At this time, the temporary `std::function` holds `l_2` and `*this` holds `l_1`. After the `swap` the temporary holds `l_1` and `*this` holds `l_2` (*). Then the temporary is destroyed and so is `l_1`.

In summary, while running `operator()` on `l_1` this object gets destroyed. Then according to 12.7/1

> > For an object with a non-trivial constructor, referring to any non-static member or base class of the object before the constructor begins execution results in undefined behavior. **For an object with a non-trivial destructor, referring to any non-static member or base class of the object after the destructor finishes execution results in undefined behavior.**

Lambdas non static data members correspond its captures. So if you don't access them, then it should be fine.

There's one more important point raised by [Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1774667/yakk)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23357600/1137388). As far as I understand, the concern was whether `std::function::operator()`, after having forwarded the call to `l_1`, tries to access `l_1` (which is now dead) or not? I don't think this is the case because the effects of `std::function::operator()` don't imply that. Indeed, 20.8.11.2.4 says that the effect of this call is

> > `INVOKE(f, std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)..., R)` (20.8.2), where `f` is the target object (20.8.1) of `*this`.

which basicallky says that `std::function::operator()` calls `l_1.operator()` and does nothing else (at least, nothing that is detectable).

(*) I'm putting details on how the interchange happens under the carpet but the idea remains valid. (E.g. what if the temporary holds a copy of `l_1` and not a pointer to it?)