# Can a std::function's target callable legally destroy the std::function during execution?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

In comments under another question, it was stated that a common mistake is to:

> invoke `std::function` when calling it leads to destruction of object which holds it

While clearly a "dangerous" thing to do that would be avoided in robust code, is it actually wrong? I cannot find any wording in the standard that ensures:

- A `std::function` must not be destroyed by its target callable
- A `std::function`'s lifetime must not end during execution of its target callable
- The lifetime of a functor in general must not end during its execution

To my knowledge, it is legal and well-defined (though in poor taste) to do things like the following:

```
struct Foo
{
   void baz()
   {
      delete this;
      // Just don't use any members after this point
   }
};

int main()
{
   Foo* foo = new Foo();
   foo->baz();
}
```

This suggests that, in the absence of any overriding restrictions, none of which I can find, the following would also be *technically* well-defined:

```
#include <functional>

struct Bar
{
   std::function<void()> func;
};

int main()
{
   Bar* bar = new Bar();
   bar->func = [&]() { delete bar; };
   bar->func();
}
```

Is this not the case? If not, which wording prohibits it?

*(For bonus points, it would be interesting if this has changed since previous standards.)*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23357600/817643 ?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I don't know about that; the standard [says nothing about any "internal state object"](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.wrap.func.inv) or anything else; only that the target is called. That's it. If an implementation chooses to do something else, surely that's the implementation taking liberties, not the user of the feature who seems to be abiding by the rules! As a result, I don't think this case falls into the "not specified in the wording, therefore UB" category; I think, at best, implementations are imposing additional requirements/constraints.

Comment: I've seen objects have `if (self_destruct) delete this;` which seems same-ish.  Also seems to be in poor taste, but I hope legal because there is a lot of it in my project's codebase.

Comment: Possibly falls into "implementation defined" behavior. If there's nothing in the standard that says you can or cannot destroy a function object while it is executing, then it sounds like it is open for interpretation as to which way to go.

Comment: While `delete this;` may be legal, I have yet to find a situation where that's what I wanted to *do*. There seems to always be other/better options available.

Comment: @JesperJuhl That's established

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm That would be UB if so (implementation-definedness, per my recollection, has to be explicitly ordained by the standard). But, as above, I'm not convinced this falls into that category. It would be like saying it's UB to use a `bool` because the standard doesn't tell us whether or not we can do so while eating pasta. If, as the programmer, you meet all the preconditions of a function call, then you should be able to expect a well-defined result. And, from my reading of the linked passages, that's all this hypothetical terrible programmer is doing.

Comment: It may be interesting to note that [there is a specific provision for exactly this, as pertains to `unique_ptr`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62930823/4386278).

Answer (score 1):

[res.on.objects]/2:

> If an object of a standard library type is accessed, and the beginning
> of the object's lifetime does not happen before the access, or the
> access does not happen before the end of the object's lifetime, the
> behavior is undefined unless otherwise specified. [ Note: This applies
> even to objects such as mutexes intended for thread synchronization. —
> end note ]

As far as the library is concerned, a member function can access the object until it returns. It follows that destroying the object in the middle of such a call is undefined unless permission is explicitly granted.

Comment: But does a function call count, as a unit, as an "access"? [It doesn't for `unique_ptr`'s deleter, apparently...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62930823/4386278) I'd therefore interpret this as meaning actual accesses to member data. That being said, it's interesting that there is a specific rule here as you'd expect it to be covered by the general rules for not "accessing" objects that don't exist. I'm starting to think it's a little underspecified, or at least possibly ambiguous...